# It wasn't as good as it is (now)

Tags: comparatives

The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language says  this (Page 1119):

> **Temporal contrasts**
>
> The main contrast may be a matter of time, expressed by tense:
>
> [38] i *It is better than* [*it was*].
>
> ii *It wasn't as good as* [*it is now*].
>
> Note, however, that where contrastive present time is associated with the comparative clause the present tense normally needs reinforcing with a temporal modifier: it would be unusual to drop *now* from [ii].

I don't understand why 'now' is required in [ii].

Why is this sentence unusual?

> *It wasn't as good as it is.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **as it is** *phrase*
>   In the existing circumstances.
>   ‘I've got enough on my plate as it is’
>   [- ODO](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/as_(it)_is)

The words “as it is” are something of a Swiss Army knife. They can be a temporal contrast as your post suggests, but they are also such a common throwaway phrase that your intent might not come through.

Answer (score 0):

I can't cite chapter and verse, but I believe that the situation informs the tense, but not *vice versa*. Thus, with temporal comparisons, the thing before requires the past tense, and the thing now requires the present tense.  But the mere *use* of the tenses does not communicate unambiguously that the thing stated in the past tense occurred in the past or that the thing stated in the present is in the present.

*E.g.*, "as it is" is an idiom that means "as things stand now" - as in:

```
He's not speaking to me these days. I would like to see him, but, as it is, that's impossible.
```

The present tense is also used historically:

```
Just put yourself back then.  It's summertime, and the livin' is easy.
```

Or we use the past tense verb form for counterfactuals:

```
If I were you, ...
```

One might say that the relationship between tense and time is one-to-many, which means that the semantic cues given by using tense without an intensifier to communicate time are one too few.

Comment: Just a note on formatting: using a “>” at the start of each line produces more readable quotes than indenting the lines.

Comment: But your answer cannot explain the part "contrastive present time is associated with the comparative clause". That is, I don't think the same thing can be said about this sentence: _It isn't as good now as it was._ Here, I don't think dropping _now_ would result in an unusual construction: _It isn't as good as it was._ Don't you agree?

Comment: @jk2 - Context fills all sorts of ellipses. That the tense cannot be counted on to communicate time does not mean it cannot be used to do so adequately in the right situations, which may be many. A useful exercise is to write "the same letter" to a friend, a stranger, and posterity.  In one version, you might use "now," and in another, you might not. (Note the word "normally" in the "rule." I suspect the "rule" is more descriptive than prescriptive.)